# Thread-safe in-memory cache

Tags: multithreading, scala

I need a simple thread-safe in-memory cache in my Scala application.

I need a data structure which support this operation from `scala.collection.mutable.MapLike`:

```
def getOrElseUpdate(key: A, op: => B)
```

and I want this operation to be atomic. Is this operation atomic in `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap`? Or should I use some other data structure?

I use Scala 2.10, but will probably upgrade to 2.11 soon.

I don't want to use `scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap`, since it is deprecated in Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 4):

[TrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap) is appropriate for such a case

> A concurrent hash-trie or TrieMap is a concurrent thread-safe lock-free implementation of a hash array mapped trie.

And `getOrElseupdate` in TrieMap is thread-safe to use. So yes you should use it. As per [this](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~prokopec/ctries-snapshot.pdf), triemap is actually awesome when the insertion rate is really high. Though the difference can be hardly observed.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, `TrieMap` does not override `getOrElseUpdate`, which makes this method **not** thread safe.

[SI-7943 TrieMap method getOrElseUpdate is not thread-safe](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7943)

Comment: Looks like this was fixed late 2.11.x (see https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4319)